# How to test for character references in Symfony with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, character-reference

I want to test this very simple page generated by my PHP/Symfony project

```
            <div>Simple&nbsp;! Tranquille&nbsp;! Excellent&nbsp;!</div>
```

(It's in French, so it needs the `&nbsp;` hard spaces in front of the exclamation points.)

I thought an equally simple test such as

```
        $this->assertSelectorTextContains('div', 'Simple&nbsp;! Tranquille&nbsp;! Excellent&nbsp;!');
```

would do the trick, but I get a failure.

Further inquiry shows that

```
        $texte = $crawler->filter("div")->first();
        $this->assertEquals($texte->text(), "Simple&nbsp;! Tranquille&nbsp;! Excellent&nbsp;!");
```

returns

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Simple ! Tranquille ! Excellent !'
+'Simple&nbsp;! Tranquille&nbsp;! Excellent&nbsp;!'
```

So, how do I help `assertSelectorTextContains()` (and more generally, PHPUnit) understand that both strings are actually the same? (Or at least equivalent?)

Comment: FYI: IIRC the _assertSelectorTextContains_ assertion is from Symfony (not Phpunit) and as you already found out, the text is without the HTML entities. The encoding of the text likely is UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing my search criteria yielded the answer, `html_entity_decode()`:

```
        $this->assertSelectorTextContains('div', html_entity_decode('Simple&nbsp;! Tranquille&nbsp;! Excellent&nbsp;!'));
```

does the job.

Comment: You can also try with a double quoted string and the unicode codepoint escape syntax: `"Simple\u{A0}! ..."` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double